# Shouldn't I Never display a form or a messagebox from a thread?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have always been displaying such things in the main thread and using events to synchronize the end of a window with a thread to let it know when the windows is closed.

Today, during development I wanted to move displayed form from thread to main UI, but it successfully was displayed. The only thing I added is that in the main thread I am pushing messages waiting on the event:

```
procedure WaitWithMessageLoop();
var
vWaitForEventHandles:array[0..1] of THandle;
vWaitForResponse:DWORD;
Msg: TMSG;
begin
vWaitForEventHandles[0] := LServiceMonitor.Handle;
while (1=1) do
begin
  vWaitForResponse := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, vWaitForEventHandles, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
  if (vWaitForResponse = WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1) then
  begin
    while (PeekMessage(msg,0,0,0,PM_REMOVE)) do
    begin
      TranslateMessage(msg);
      DispatchMessage(msg);
    end;
  end
  else
  if (vWaitForResponse = WAIT_FAILED)
    then RaiseLastOSError
    else break;
end;
end;
```

So my question is. Is a such scenerio acceptable? Or Should I move a form to be displayed in the main thread?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't make it clear enough how this all fits together. Where is the form that you are displaying?

Comment: Currently the form is instantiated and displayed in a thread. The event I am waiting on (as above) just gives me the info when that thread will finish its job. (It also push messages to display messages send from a thread)

Comment: You can't reliably run VCL forms outside the main GUI thread. Don't even think about trying to do so. Run your form from the main GUI thread like you know you are supposed to do. I assume that the code in the question runs in the thread? `while 1=1` is better written `while True`. Why does the loop not break when the wait returns successfully. `WAIT_FAILED` is an odd termination criterion.

Comment: The code snippet I posted runs in a main thread. Anyway thank you, I will move the code which displays the form. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reliably run VCL forms outside the main GUI thread. When you try to do this, it may appear to work, but at some point in the future such code will fail. Most likely on your most important clients machine, in a particularly critical manner!

The VCL was designed such that all VCL forms are created and operated on from the main GUI thread only. If you need to invoke VCL forms then you have to use tools like `TThread.Synchronize` to make sure that the forms are created on the GUI thread.

Comment: Beware: depending on the Delphi version, calling `TThread.Synchronize` from a thread, while the main thread is not handling messages because it's stuck in `TThread.WaitFor`, will cause a deadlock. I *think* it's Delphi 6 and higher that handle this properly, and this question is about Delphi 7, so it *should* just work, but I could easily be misremembering the first Delphi version that allows this.

Comment: @hvd Hmm, but everything would break if you called `TThread.WaitFor` from the main GUI thread.

Comment: Doesn't this question ask exactly that? `WaitWithMessageLoop` is called from the main thread, because the main thread is waiting for another thread to finish. There are some cases when waiting for other threads to finish is acceptable, particularly if you've just called `TThread.Terminate` and need to wait until the thread has noticed.

Comment: @hvd Yes but the code here uses `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` so that the wait can be interrupted by windows messages. And IIRC that's how `Synchronize` works.

Comment: That is how `Synchronize` used to work, and the change I'm talking about is that `Synchronize` now uses events, and `TThread.WaitFor` processes `Synchronize` requests.

Comment: (By events, I'm referring to what Windows calls events, not what Delphi calls events.)

Comment: @hvd and @DavidHeffernan: calling `WaitFor()` in the main thread does not block it from processing messages, even in D5. `WaitFor() runs an internal message loop. `Synchronize()` can be called while `WaitFor()` is running. In D5 and earlier, `Synchronize()`  used `SendMessage()`, and `WaitFor()` checks for sent messages. `In D6, `Synchronize()` was re-written to not use `SendMessage()` anymore, but it does use `PostMessage()` to wake up the main thread so it can call `CheckSynchronize()` if it is idle. `WaitFor()` calls `CheckSynchronize()` inside its internal message loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, `WaitFor` does not process messages. Have a look at the code. Nowhere in `WaitFor` are messages processed. Yes, messages that are sent to this thread may be delivered, but queued messages are not processed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `WaitFor` calls `PeekMessage(..., PM_NOREMOVE)`, which indeed is supposed to process *sent* messages (but not *posted* messages), and D5 `Synchronize` calls *`SendMessage`*, so you're right that it *should* handle this properly. I don't recall the exact details of when it failed, but I do recall that it failed. Perhaps it was an even older Delphi version that had the problem I'm describing, or perhaps it only appears in specific scenarios that are more complex than simply waiting on a thread. Thanks for the correction, it's at least not as simple as I thought.

Comment: @Remy and @hvd My point is that calling `WaitFor` from the main thread of a GUI app results in a dead ghosted main window

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It doesn't, not when the thread will actually be finishing soon. I mentioned calling `WaitFor` after calling `Terminate`, and assuming (it can be a safe assumption when it's your own code and you took this into account) that the thread periodically checks `Terminated` and exits when it's set, there's no problem.

Comment: @hvd I beg to differ. If the thread finishes immediately then yes, no ghosting. If the thread takes time to finish then you have a hang and a ghost. What else did you think I meant?!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Considering I had already mentioned `Terminate` earlier, and you repeated your (otherwise usually correct) claim that `WaitFor` causes ghosting, I did not know what you meant. But I think we're in agreement now.

Comment: Ghosting is when the window is drawn faded and Windows adds (Not Responding) to the applications caption bar. Try writing a simple VCL app and adding `Sleep(30000)` to a event handler.